# getModel returns object but "load()" is called on boolean?

Tags: php, database, magento, model, resources

This is my first Magento model, and I'm having trouble. I have looked through some of the Magento core modules in order to try and find the error in what I'm doing, and as far as I can tell everything is the exact same save for the names and the tables.

I'm working with Magento 1.9.

The following code...

```
$test = Mage::getModel('employee/user');
var_dump($test);
$test->load($params['id']);
```

Yields...

```
object(Dot_Employee_Model_User)#139 (15) { ["_eventPrefix":protected]=> string(13) "core_abstract" ["_eventObject":protected]=> string(6) "object" ["_resourceName":protected]=> string(13) "employee/user" ["_resource":protected]=> NULL ["_resourceCollectionName":protected]=> string(24) "employee/user_collection" ["_cacheTag":protected]=> bool(false) ["_dataSaveAllowed":protected]=> bool(true) ["_isObjectNew":protected]=> NULL ["_data":protected]=> array(0) { } ["_hasDataChanges":protected]=> bool(false) ["_origData":protected]=> NULL ["_idFieldName":protected]=> NULL ["_isDeleted":protected]=> bool(false) ["_oldFieldsMap":protected]=> array(0) { } ["_syncFieldsMap":protected]=> array(0) { } } 
Fatal error: Call to a member function load() on boolean in www.example.com/somePath/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php on line 225
```

I have the following config.xml...

```
<models>
        <employee>
          <class>Dot_Employee_Model</class>
          <resourceModel>employee_resource></resourceModel>
        </employee>
        <employee_resource>
          <class>Dot_Employee_Model_Resource</class>
          <entities>
            <ipwhitelist>
              <table>dot_employee_ipwhitelist</table>
            </ipwhitelist>
            <user>
              <table>dot_employee_user</table>
            </user>
          </entities>
        </employee_resource>
      </models>
```

And here is an example file set from one of my models...

**Model/Ipwhitelist.php**

```
class Dot_Employee_Model_Ipwhitelist extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
  protected function _construct()
  {
    parent::_construct();
    $this->_init('employee/ipwhitelist');
  }
}
```

**Model/Resource/Ipwhitelist.php**

```
class Dot_Employee_Model_Resource_Ipwhitetable extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract
{
  protected function _construct()
  {
    $this->_init('employee/ipwhitetable', 'ip_id');
  }
}
```

**Model/Resource/Ipwhitelist/Collection.php**

```
class Dot_Employee_Model_Mysql4_Ipwhitelist_Collection extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Collection_Abstract
  {
    public function _construct()
    {
      $this->_init('employee/ipwhitelist');
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

change the following file 
**Model/Resource/Ipwhitelist.php**

```
class Dot_Employee_Model_Resource_Ipwhitelist extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract
{
protected function _construct()
  {
      $this->_init('employee/ipwhitetable', 'ip_id');
  }
}
```

You have wrongly entered the class name as Ipwhitetable instead of Ipwhitelist.
And need to verify the table name declarations are correct.

I hope it will help you.

Comment: Did you fixed or still having that issue

Comment: whether check you are giving correct id for that particular table.$this->_init('employee/ipwhitetable', 'ip_id') replace the 'ip_id' as id like following  $this->_init('employee/ipwhitetable', 'id');